# getting started express.io first simplest example

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying this simple example:

Server:

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection')
})

app.listen(50000)
```

Client:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client').connect('http://localhost:50000')

io.on('connect', function (sock) {
    console.log("socket connected")
})
```

Neither 'connection' nor 'socket connected' appears in nodejs console

However separate express and socket.io server works like a charm:

```
var app = require('express')()
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection')
})

http.listen(50000)
```

I'd like to get it done with express.io for educational purposes, but there is no forum, no archives, ...nowhere to ask

Comment: that project wasn't touched for the last 3 years... maybe just stick with your second solution? Or try and ask on github directly as an issue?

Comment: may be you should use `app.io.route` instead of `app.io.on`. As CFrei said, the project wasn't touched for last 3 years, maybe you should choose your second solution.